# Как происходит покрытие тестами методов класса?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Настраивала проект на покрытие тестами (в частности интересует **интеграционное тестирование**) и, кажется, не правильно поняла как это делать. В частности, после настройки *PhpUnit* у меня был класс:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

class Tmp {
    public function hello() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

и я думала, что если записать метод с именем `testHello` и там произвести проверки, то *PHPUnit* автоматически должен проверять метод `hello` класса `Tmp` (как-то под капотом создать и проверить). Пример класса с тестом:

```
<?php
        namespace tests\unit\models;

        use Codeception\Test\Unit;

        class TmpTest extends Unit {                
            /**
             * @var \UnitTester
             */
            protected $tester;              
            protected function _before() { }                
            protected function _after() { }
            
            public function testHello() {
                // Здесь всякие assert'ы
            }
        }
```

Но покрытие показывало 0%. Когда же я в методе написала напрямую вызов метода

```
public function testHello() {
    $this->assertEquals(1, (new Tmp())->hello());
}
```

то покрытие показало 100%

Получается не важно как назван метод для покрытия конкретного метода конкретного класса? Чтобы покрывать тестами методы и то, что внутри, надо напрямую их вызывать? Как вообще правильно делать так называемое покрытие тестами?

Comment: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, нужно вызывать методы, которые вы тестируете.

По-первых, в большинстве случаев у метода будут какие-то параметры, он будет возвращать значение. Еще у него могут быть побочные эффекты.

Никакая автоматическая система не сможет за вас догадаться, какие параметры подать на вход метода, какие из них должны считаться допустимыми, как результат метода связан с входящими параметрами. Это знаете только вы.

Далее в методе у вас может быть какая-то логика, т.е. в зависимости от входных параметров могут выполняться разные действия. Опять же, что должно происходить знаете только вы. И какие сценарии проверять тоже знаете только вы.

Поэтому, в тесте придется делать все как надо, а именно:

1. подготовить тестовые данные. Это могут быть входящие параметры, глобальное состояние (например, записи в БД).
2. вызвать метод с нужными параметрами
3. проверить, что произошло то, что ожидается в этом сценарии. Тут речь идет как о результате метода, так и о побочных эффектах, например, изменении состояния в БД.

Comment: Да, спасибо, кажется я это уж всё поняла) Спасибо за разъяснения